# Convert android app to IOS using phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I developed an android application with Phonegap and I want to convert it to iOS as well. Before starting my project I heard that we are able to convert same project with multiple platforms using phone gap. But now I don't know how to convert my project to IOS. Can any one suggest good tutorial OR examples to do it.

And also mention what are all prerequisites to convert my android application to IOS using phone gap.

Suggest me some tutorials with examples.

Comment: Everything you should need is here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html . Which  specific problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **phongap you can target all platforms including iOS, android and windows** etc. using HTML 5, avoiding each mobile platforms' native development language. **Code base remains same for every platform**. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's sensors, data, and network status. refer docs http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

Comment: In my android project i have used java classes in src folder to send email. Is there any problem to build IOS for same source code?

Comment: use this plugin https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap **is not for converting one build to another**.. Using phonegap you can develope for all platforms using phonegap framework, you can generate .apk,.ipa,ota, etc as you wish using sdk in your pc or using [phonegap build service](http://html.adobe.com/edge/phonegap-build/). You can read [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html)(phonegap authentic doc) how can you do it for different plaforms.

Nb:Phonegap provides complete documents in their site itself, you can go through and understand, it is helpfull.

Comment: In my android project i have used java classes in src folder to send email. Is there any problem to build IOS for same source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can build on each platform. If you don't want to do that, they offer a Build service that build your app on each platform for you. See https://build.phonegap.com/ for more info.
With `phonegap` you can create all platform application with same package just you need to clear yourself that for `IOS` you need `certificates` to build it. Otherwise same package you are using for android can use for `IOS` also.

Comment: In my android project i have used java classes in src folder to send email. Is there any problem to build IOS for same source code?